# Silverlight BitmapImage cache not working

Tags: xaml, silverlight, caching

I need to cache the image, but it doesn't cache.

I have following converter :

```cs
public class ImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                         System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
   {
      Uri uri = new Uri(UrlParser.GetRootURL() + "/Output/" + (int)value);
      BitmapImage bitmapimage = new BitmapImage(uri) 
        { 
            CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation | BitmapCreateOptions.BackgroundCreation 
        };
      return this.bitmapimage;
   }
}
```

XAML :

```xml
<Image Source="{Binding Id, Converter={StaticResource imageSourceConverter}}" 
       MaxHeight="150" MaxWidth="120" />
```

Any ideas on how cache them?

Comment: Did you try to specify the UriSource property after setting CreateOptions? Like `new BitmapImage { CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.BackgroundCreation, UriSource = uri }`

Comment: Yes, I had already tried . It didn't work

Comment: @furqanms, Can you confirm if the headers of the responses for those images have any cache control. Silverlight is also bound by the browser it is hosted in. If the browser does not know to cache the image then every time silverlight makes the call for the image it will make a new request. If you have control of the server providing the images then make sure that the images also provide caching information. That should fixed your problem.

Comment: Yes, MCV OutputCache is there.